# Elasticsearch - How do I query for results where a specific field has changed over time

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'll preface this with the statement that I'm a newcomer to elasticsearch so this may have an easy answer.  Nothing I've read to date has clicked as a way that would allow me to achieve the below.

A very simplified scenario. I have a sequence of user activities like so:

```
timestamp: t0, user: mike, result: failed
timestamp: t1, user: anne, result: failed
timestamp: t2, user: bob,  result: success
timestamp: t3, user: tom,  result: success
timestamp: t4, user: jane, result: failed
timestamp: t5, user: anne, result: success
timestamp: t6, user: tom,  result: failed
timestamp: t7, user: jane, result: failed
timestamp: t8, user: mike, result: success
```

I need to identify all users that have had to work hard to reach a successful outcome (I'm ignoring those that were never successful). For this purpose all I really need to do is find records where a user failed one or more times before they succeeded.

With the sequence above the results are those records with user of 'anne' or a user of 'mike'.

We ignore 'jane' as there was no success and we ignore 'bob' as there was no failure. We would also ignore 'tom' as they were successful first then failed - that is a different case again.

I can do this relatively easily in SQL but I'm stumped how I would achieve this within elasticsearch.

How would you form a query to answer this question?

Or, even better, how could I rephrase my question to reach the same outcome?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be conceivable for you to have a different domain model, where you have a single doc per user and an array of timestamped results, like `{"user":"mike", "results":[{"timestamp":"t0", "result":"failed"},{"timestamp":"t8", "result":"success"}]}`? Or do you absolutely want to have discrete documents for each event?

Comment: I'm not tied to the domain model at all - the current structure is much easier to work with in terms of our current data processing but happy to look at alternatives. How would your proposed structure be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great problem. It took a little effort to figure it out, but I managed to get it to work using the new [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) in ES 2.0.

I had to change the timestamps to `"integer"` type to get it to work (it would work with dates as well, though).

I created a trivial index and added your data with a `_bulk` request:

```
PUT /test_index

POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"timestamp": 0,"user":"mike","result":"failed"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"timestamp": 1,"user":"anne","result":"failed"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"timestamp": 2,"user":"bob","result":"success"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"timestamp": 3,"user":"tom","result":"success"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"timestamp": 4,"user":"jane","result":"failed"}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"timestamp": 5,"user":"anne","result":"success"}
{"index":{"_id":7}}
{"timestamp": 6,"user":"tom","result":"failed"}
{"index":{"_id":8}}
{"timestamp": 7,"user":"jane","result":"failed"}
{"index":{"_id":9}}
{"timestamp": 8,"user":"mike","result":"success"}
```

Then I can get what you are asking for (I think) with the following query. Under the top-level `"user_terms"` aggregation, I can set up three sub-aggregations:

- `"failed_filter"` selects documents that have `"result": "failed"`, and then a sub aggregation finds the maximum timestamp in that group;
- `"success_filter"` selects documents that have `"result": "success"`, and then a sub aggregation finds the maximum timestamp in *that* group;
- finally, `"failed_lt_success_filter"` selects only those documents for which the (maximum) timestamp attached to the failed value is less than the (maximum) timestamp attached to the success value.

Whew.

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggregations": {
      "user_terms": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "user"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "failed_filter": {
               "filter": { "term": { "result": "failed" } },
               "aggs": {
                  "max_timestamp": { "max": { "field": "timestamp" } }
               }
            },
            "success_filter": {
               "filter": { "term": { "result": "success" } },
               "aggs": {
                  "max_timestamp": { "max": { "field": "timestamp" } }
               }
            },
            "failed_lt_success_filter": {
               "bucket_selector": {
                  "buckets_path": {
                     "failed_timestamp": "failed_filter.max_timestamp",
                     "success_timestamp": "success_filter.max_timestamp"
                  },
                  "script": "failed_timestamp < success_timestamp"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which returns:

```
{
   "took": 11,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 9,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "user_terms": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "anne",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "success_filter": {
                  "doc_count": 1,
                  "max_timestamp": {
                     "value": 5
                  }
               },
               "failed_filter": {
                  "doc_count": 1,
                  "max_timestamp": {
                     "value": 1
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "mike",
               "doc_count": 2,
               "success_filter": {
                  "doc_count": 1,
                  "max_timestamp": {
                     "value": 8
                  }
               },
               "failed_filter": {
                  "doc_count": 1,
                  "max_timestamp": {
                     "value": 0
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some code I used to play around with the problem:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/06083e06191445a44610f32baf1dd45c7370401e

Comment: Thanks Sloan, thats given me a much better insight into how I can use multiple filters! The timestamp field will be a real timestamp, apologies for my pseudo-data throwing you off. Your query returns bucketed results - what about if I just wanted the matching records without any aggregation?

Comment: Nice solution @SloanAhrens! @Andrew, you can add another `top_hits` aggregation as a sub-aggregation of the `user_terms` aggregation and you'll get the matching documents.